# Adding defaults to integer columns, error saying 'right sytnax near 'default-1 default null'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a column named 'parent_id' that I am trying to add a default of -1 to:

```
change_column  :categories, :parent_id, :default => -1
```

The type is a integer in mysql.

I am getting the error:

```
'mysql2 error......'default-1 default null' at line 1:
alter table 'categories' change 'parent_id' 'parent_id' default-1 default null
```

It seems it is missing = sign?

Also, how do I do a db:migrate on the test db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the column type in your `change_column`, it should be more like this:

```
change_column :categories, :parent_id, :integer, :default => -1
```

The giveaway is this: `default-1`. The `change_column` method wants three arguments and then a hash of optional arguments. Your `:default => -1` is getting mashed together as the column type because you didn't specify `:integer` as the third argument.